# How to show a button based off when an item in a radio button list is selected

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have tried multiple ways to get the button to show up but nothing is working.

This is what I have in the c# code:

```
protected void rblistcourses_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnremoveselectedcourse.Visible = true;

    }
```

And this is the HTMl aspx portion

```
<asp:Button ID="btnremoveselectedcourse" runat="server"
     OnClick="btnremoveselectedcourse_Click" Text="Remove selected"
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblistcourses_OnSelectedIndexChanged" 
     AutoPostBack="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
```

Comment: Show your markup for the radio button list. It likely needs an autopostback=true

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with asp.net, but looking at your code it looks like the `rblistcourses_OnSelectedIndexChanged` event should be assigned to your `RadioButton` or `RadioButtonList`, not to your `btnremoveselectedcourse`.

The `btnremoveselectedcourse` will be the changed by the `rblistcourses_OnSelectedIndexChanged` event, but another component must call it, or it will never happen.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question that could well be served by using client-side code (JavaScript).

However, for now, given that server-side code was posted, then the following server-side code will work:

```
    protected void RBList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Button1.Visible = !(RBList1.SelectedIndex == 0);  
        Button2.Visible = !(RBList1.SelectedIndex == 1);  
        Button3.Visible = !(RBList1.SelectedIndex == 2);  

    }
```

And the result is this:

[image]

And the markup:

```
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RBList1" runat="server" 
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
        CssClass="rMyChoice"
        AutoPostBack="true"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="RBList1_SelectedIndexChanged"
    >
        <asp:ListItem>Hide Button One</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Hide Button Two</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Hide Button Three</asp:ListItem>

    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div style="float:left;width:200px">
        &nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
            Text="Button 1"
            CssClass="btn"
            />
    </div>

    <div style="float:left;width:200px">
        &nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" 
            Text="Button 2"
            CssClass="btn"
            />
    </div>

    <div style="float:left;width:200px">
        &nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" 
            Text="Button 3"
            CssClass="btn"
            />
    </div>
```